# String mask in perl for know format variations

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to pull information from a list of folders that are organised in a logical manner but have optional parts.

Below is my folder structure with optional fields noted inside <> :

```
artist - album_nr. album_title <(type)> <(issue_info)> (year) [quality]
```

So some examples of directories would be named like this

```
Emperor - 03. Reverence (EP) (1997) [flac]
Emperor - 05b. IX Equilibrium (reissue 2007) (1999) [cue-flac]
Exodus - 01a. Bonded    By Blood (1985) [cue-flac]
Exodus - 01b. Bonded By Blood    (remaster 2008) (1985) [cue-flac]
Exodus - 03.Tempo of the Damned    (EP) (remaster 2008) (1985) [cue-flac]
```

I need a regex that will correctly pull the relevant parts into an array for further processing but am struggling , mostly because of the optional fields.

At most, the array will contain 7 pieces of information and 5 pieces of information at the very least.

If anyone can help me I will be extremely grateful and it will save me a lot of manual effort.

Comment: _I need a regex_ ... No, you need to learn regex first.

Comment: That's helpful. I use regex once in a blue moon to do some processing I might need done for personal use at home. Since that's about one time every 18 months I forget it as fast as I learn it. The problem is probably trivial for someone who uses it day in/out but not for someone used to completely different programming methods.

Comment: @Reptile: The problem is, most people on the site are here to help each other learn. When you say that you're not interested in learning, you're saying that there's nothing for people to help you with.

Comment: If I want to argue with people I would go to online newspaper comments. I never once said I am not interested in learning, I need a solution to part of a problem I am struggling with and have been messing around for hours trying to solve the regex I require and am struggling to get it right. Why do people feel the need to put others right? If you don't want to help just move on.

Comment: @Reptile because this site exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using extended notation for legibility:

```
my $re = qr/
    ([^-]+?)          # artist
    \h*               # 
    -                 # literal '-'
    \h*               # 
    ([0-9]+[a-z]?)    # album number
    \.                # literal '.'
    \h*               # 
    ([^(]+?)          # album title
    \h*               # 
    (?:\(([^)]+)\))?  # type (optional)
    \h*               # 
    (?:\(([^)]+)\))?  # issue info (optional)
    \h*               # 
    \(([^)]+)\)       # year
    \h*               # 
    \[(.+)\]          # quality
/x;
```

Note that this regex always returns seven values (on match) because there are seven captures.

The "trick" to the optional parts you said you were having trouble with is to 
navigate among capturing, non-capturing, and literal parentheses. Those portions of the regex break down as follows:

```
(?:    # begin non-capturing grouping (for '?' quantifier at the end)
\(     # literal '('
(      # begin capture
[^)]+  # any character other than ')', one or more times
)      # end capture
\)     # literal ')'
)      # end non-capturing grouping
?      # zero or one quantifier (make everything in group optional)
```

Edit: In the comments, Jerry correctly points out that there's potential ambiguity about what matched when only one of the optional fields (type or issue info) is present in the data. This can be fixed by making the regex less permissive (at the risk of failing to match some data -- always check whether or not a match was successful). This works for the sample data you provided:

```
(?:\((\w+\h+[0-9]{4}+)\))? # issue info (optional)
```

If we do that, it also seems prudent to make the year more restrictive as well.

```
\(([0-9]{4})\) # year
```

Comment: Thanks! I will work with this and see how it goes and post the final result.

Comment: I would use a slightly different regex if I were you. The idea is good, but if each of the fields are important, then you shouldn't get an `issue_info` field into where the `type` field should be. You see it a bit clearer with named captures: [link](http://regex101.com/r/gT8gM1) as opposed to [link](http://regex101.com/r/vN0zN0). OP didn't mention all the rules, but that's as far as what the sample informs about.

Comment: Yes, your 2nd link provides a more reliable match on the information specified. Thanks for everyone's input. I now have a base to work with so I can further improve other areas of the extraction process. I hope to use this to fill the tags in my collect with this info.